# 'python.analysis.typeCheckingMode'. Error: Unable to write to Folder Settings because no resource is provided

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I get this error when I open vs code. I have everything updated to the latest version. Type checking doesn't work.

I re-installed Python and vs code with all extensions, but the Pylance doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can [this answer in github](https://github.com/coder/code-server/issues/3873#issuecomment-912100324) solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code in your `settings.json`:

```
"workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb"
},
```